# Copy Directory files to another directory in batch file without asking?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have created a batch file to copy one folders files to another folder.
This code `XCOPY C:\Temp\a.txt C:\Temp2\a.txt /Q` works but when i run this file it ask `Overwrite C:\Temp2\a.txt (Yes/No/All)?`
I want to do this without asking this question. How can i do ? And i want to this for aspx or aspx.cs files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> /Y Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing
>   destination file

So just add the /Y option in order to overwrite all files without asking.

If you want to copy all files that contain "aspx", you can use

```
XCOPY C:\Temp\aspx* C:\Temp2\ /Q /Y
```

Comment: I want to ask one question too. This code works for any folder but not working for project publish folder. I couldn't copy any folder's file to asp.net publish directory, I have controlled folders write/read permission

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

> XCOPY C:\Temp\a.txt C:\Temp2\a.txt /Q /Y